# Use of "compared to" as found in a dictionary

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

I read that "compared to" is used to indicate similarities between things of a different nature. So is this sentence

> I'm a slob compared to my roommate.

from this dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compared%20to

wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *(when)* compared to

can not only compare *similarities*, it can also describe *differences* and makes the comparison *relative* to what something is being "*compared to*"

Your example sentence is correct

> I'm a slob **compared to** my roommate.
>   I'm tall **compared to** my roommate.

The comparison is *relative*, so if you're only 5'2" and your roommate is 4'1", you would be "tall".

Comment: Does the same apply to "When she was dressed in such a casual way—compared to her tiptop classy, groomed from head-to-toes appearance in public—she looked like a thirty-six rather than a forty-three-year-old woman. "?